# Clearcase : list of files removed in latest label

Tags: clearcase

In Clearcase, I need to find difference between two labels which include new added files, modified files and removed files in new label.

I have used the below script, but it is not giving me correct data:

```
#!/bin/sh
REL_LBL_1=REL1_7
REL_LBL_2=REL1_8

echo "\n ${REL_LBL_2} versions of files that replaced ${REL_LBL_1}
versions ..."
echo "====================================================="
cleartool find -avobs -element "{lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_2}) &&
lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_1})}" -version "{lbtype(${REL_LBL_2}) && !
lbtype(${REL_LBL_1})}" -print

echo "\n Files created new to ${REL_LBL_2} ..."
echo "====================================================="
cleartool find -avobs -element "{lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_2}) && !
lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_1})}" -version "lbtype(${REL_LBL_2})" -print

echo "\n ${REL_LBL_1} files removed in ${REL_LBL_2} ..."
echo "====================================================="
cleartool find -avobs -element "{lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_1}) &&
lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_2})}" -version "lbtype(${REL_LBL_1})" -print
```

Comment: What is incorrect? What is missing? (and what version of ClearCase are you using, on which OS?)

Comment: list of removed files is giving wrong, clearcase version im using is 7.0.1

Comment: Is the list of removed file incomplete? Or is it *completely* wrong? Are you using it in a dynamic or snapshot view?

Comment: It is completly wrong, it is showing incorrect data, I'm using dynamic view

Comment: cleartool find -avobs -element "{lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_1}) &&
lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_2})}" -version "lbtype(${REL_LBL_1})" -print   -- output of this is displaying some files, but when i checked in the latest label, those files still exist

Comment: Don't forget to read, for your other questions, http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cleartool find -avobs -element "{lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_1}) &&
> lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_2})}" -version "lbtype(${REL_LBL_1})" -print
> ```
>
> output of this is displaying some files, but when I checked in the latest label, those files still exist

That could because those same files were added to source control *again* at some point *after* having being deleted.
Check their version history.

```
cleartool find -avobs -element "{lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_1}) &&
lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_2})}" -version "lbtype(${REL_LBL_1})" -print
```

Or that could be because that query *does* not list "files removed in ${REL_LBL_2}". It would still display any element with `${REL_LBL_2}` as well as `${REL_LBL_1}`

Try at least:

```
cleartool find -avobs -element "{lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_1}) &&
lbtype_sub(${REL_LBL_2})}" -version "lbtype(${REL_LBL_1}) && !lbtype(${REL_LBL_2})" -print
```

---

> purpose of this script is, i'm planning to migrate Clearcase to GIT, below is the plan -
>
> 1. I will put data from cleacase label-1 in GIT and apply tag label-1 in GIT.
> 2. I will findout diff between label-1 and label-2 in Clearcase and copy the diff in GIT and apply tag label-2 in GIT.
>      For the 2nd point, I will using the above script to identify, modified files, removed files and new files

The thing is... you don't need to script. At all.

Simply set your ClearCase view to label 2, and add that content to your git repo:

```
cd /path/to/git/repo
git --work-tree /path/to/clearcase/view/set/to/label_2 add .
git commit -m "Import label 2"
git tag -m "label2 import" label2
```

Git will detect automatically what has been added/modified *and* deleted!

Comment: Thanks @VonC for quick response, i have checked the version tree of those files, it is not at all deleted and the files are identical between two labels.

Comment: @user2369546 check the version tree of their parent history. You should see a version for their deletion.

Comment: i have checked the version tree of the parent directory, there is no deletion of that file, Can i not get the output ignoring intermediate deletion and addition, i need the final diff between two labels

Comment: purpose of this script is, i'm planning to migrate Clearcase to GIT, below is the plan -

1) I will put data from cleacase label-1 in GIT and apply tag label-1 in GIT
2) I will findout diff between label-1 and label-2 in Clearcase and copy the diff in GIT and apply tag label-2 in GIT.
   For the 2nd point, i will using the above script to identify, modified files, removed files and new files.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VonC, You are superb, I will try that idea. Before adding to GIT, i have to ignore some files, may be i will try to include those folders in .gitignore and will push.

Comment: @user2369546 Exactly: you can first add those ignored files to `.git/info/exclude` (https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#explicit-repository-excludes), and then start the process: that way, you are sure the `.gitignore` file itself does not get deleted by the import. Once the import is done, yuo can add your .gitignore as a file.